# Firefox won't let me select any kind of script as the protocol handler for an SSH link

Tags: macos, firefox, ssh

I'm trying to run a script when I click on a SSH link in Firefox. I have tried using the protocol handlers in the application section of the Firefox settings.

For some reason, I cannot select any kind of script as the protocol handler : these files are grayed out, and can't be clicked.

Is there a way to enable using scripts as protocol handlers? I've taken a look inside about:config, and I can't find anything useful for this situation.

I am using Firefox version 30.0 on OSX.

Comment: when you say ssh url, do you mean `ssh://` (does that exist? what'd the browser do? open a terminal?) or `sftp://`?

Comment: ssh:// It does exist, and its available in the firefox browser on Mac OSX. When I would open an ssh:// link, it would open a terminal and launch the session. In my case, I need for it to launch a script instead of opening the terminal. The option to change this is available in the firefox preferences.